# Disabling CommandManager RequerySuggested Event

Tags: c#, wpf, routed-commands

I want to test my project performance without using CommandManager RequerySuggested.
I use the following codes to disable CommandManager from firing  RequerySuggested Event.
It removes all event handlers from RequerySuggested Event.
Is there any other simpler way to achieve this.

```
List<WeakReference> fi = typeof(CommandManager).GetField("_requerySuggestedHandlers", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(typeof(CommandManager).GetField("_commandManager", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null)) as List<WeakReference>;

fi.Clear();
```

Comment: Are you using RelayCommand class or DelegateCommand class or any other Command class?

Comment: Pls see if this discussion is useful for you: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/70de3275-a4f7-4a58-b612-a2b3df941327